# System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException in Visual Studio Update 3 using Targus Laptop Dock

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015

Searched the internet for hours and cant find a solution for this; hoping someone here can help.

I'm having problems loading the Designer view in VS2015 when I'm using my second display (using displaylink via a targus laptop dock). It ONLY happens when using this display. When I switch to screen 1 (the laptop screen) the designer view loads fine, but when using the display plugged into the dock, It never loads my projects in the designer view. Always the following error:

[image]

Does anyone have a solution?

Literally have no idea whats going on; I thought it was a corrupt VS install initially so I actually have just completed a clean Windows 10 install and it hasn't made a difference. Have no worked out it seems to just be when using the display connected via the dock.

Appreciate any guidance!

Comment: I have exactly the same issue here, 'been searching for resolution for days now, any update on your side? Btw. I'm using a Dell docking station with a DisplayLink chipset

Comment: I posted my issue at DisplayLinks support forum, maybe you want to join? http://displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=64740

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this issue with a DELL Display Dock.
See here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3101540/xaml-designer-crashed-on-new-uwp-projects-after-anniversary-update

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10: I just set my laptop display as a "Make this my main display" in DisplaySettings and xaml designer works like a charm. Seemingly when "mine display" is external, visual studio attempts to write to the restricted memory area.